# Return multiple monads

Tags: haskell

I´m reading some code in Haskell and I cannot understand and found an explanation of how if a function return a IO (whatever) it can have other types before that.

This function it would be clear a Maybe that return a IO Maybe

> Maybe User -> IO (Maybe User)

But the next one from the scotty library return a monad ActionT of Text of IO Maybe??? My mind is about to explode!

> Maybe User -> ActionT Text IO (Maybe User)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type constructors in Haskell have their own "kind" system, which you can think of as a kind of type-system-for-types. The kinds themselves don't have names; instead they are represented as just stars. So:

```
Integer :: *
IO :: * -> *
```

(Actually kinds can have names, but that is a more advanced extension; never mind for now)

The [`ActionT` type constructor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.2/docs/Web-Scotty-Trans.html#t:ActionT) in Scotty takes 3 arguments and has kind

```
ActionT :: * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *
```

The types are:

- An error type, in this case `Text`.
- An "inner" monad, which must of course be a type constructor itself taking one argument. If you try passing a `Text` as this parameter GHC will report a "kind error". In this case the inner monad is `IO`.
- A return type. `ActionT` is a monad, so in this case the function you are talking about returns a `Maybe User` in exactly the same way as your first example does.

`ActionT` is a monad transformer: this means it takes an existing monad and layers more functionality on top. This allows the programmer to separate the new functionality from the monad being modified, increasing modularity.

For more insight, study the instances for `ActionT`. For instance, one of them is

```
 (Monad m, ScottyError e) => Monad (ActionT e m)
```

This says that if `m` is an instance of monad and `e` is an instance of `ScottyError` then `ActionT e m` is also an instance of monad. The kind system allows for currying in much the same way as the type system does for function application, so the `Monad` typeclass knows that it's argument must be of kind `* -> *`, and behold, `ActionT e m` does indeed have kind `* -> *`.

Comment: Great explanation!! I did not realize that ActionT was a monad transformer. I familiarized but just in Scala. Now has complete sense.